# Need help in creating a filter as in Jira using a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJs. I need to create a directive which can be applied on each column of a table. directive should filter out that particular column based on the input of the user.

There will be button corresponding to the column name. When the user clicks on the button, an input box will appear and user will input his search. Based on the search the table should be filtered out.

Something like [this](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/6CNlsa)

Comment: Sounds like you have several features/requirements. I would break down your work into smaller pieces so you can specify a more specific question. Example: start with a table bound to some data with a text input to filter that data.

Comment: @flowbee I did this and is working. What should I do next?

Comment: do you have a plunker or codepen link to what's working?

Comment: @flowbee here's the [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/rM0VddLpYa9aCRgrW2P0/) code

Comment: so now you only want to filter on a particular column?

Comment: yes. but it should be like a button. When the user clicks it, an input box should be opened and filter things out

Comment: did my script below answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript filter function to get trigger as the user is typing in the input textbox.

```
filteredList = this.listToFIlter.filter(function (el) {
            return el.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(valueToMatch) >= 0;
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom function similar to the other answer. Here's the working plunk that only filters on display name:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.notebooks = [
          {
            name: "eventTime",
            displayName: "Event Time",
            type: "date"
          },
          {
            name: "eventName",
            displayName: "Event Name",
            type: "string"
          },
          {
            name: "eventId",
            displayName: "Event Id",
            type: "number"
          },
          {
            name: "contactPerson",
            displayName: "Person",
            type: "string"
          },
          {
            name: "eventPlace",
            displayName: "Event Place",
            type: "string"
          }
        ];

        $scope.customFilter = function(element){
          console.log(element);
          if(!$scope.filterDisplay){
            return true;
          }

          if(element.displayName.toLowerCase().includes($scope.filterDisplay.toLowerCase(), 0)){
            return true;
          }
          else{
            return false;
          }
        }

}]);

</script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="userCtrl">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Only Display Name Filter:</label><input type="text" ng-model="filterDisplay" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Display Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="notebook in notebooks | filter:customFilter">
                <td>{{notebook.name}}</td>
                <td>{{notebook.displayName}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/PaiowJgDIM8sLjXZTwAH?p=preview

Comment: @kishoresrivatsa does this answer your question?